# Item Web API returning field with empty string

Tags: item-web-api

In Sitecore 7.2, I am  using the Item Web API to retrieve an item. The thing is, I get some fields as empty, and when I look in the content tree they are not empty, specifically an image type. Any ideas why?

Comment: might be a wrong path or the item was not publish

Comment: Is the database you are trying to pull from correct?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet you are using

Comment: Im just using the item web api in JS to retrieve that: http://host/-/item/v1/?query=fast:/sitecore/content/ ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the `payload` query parameter to return ALL the fields.  Otherwise, it returns only content fields.  So add:

> ...&payload=full